# ExpandableListAdapter with searchView only Group

Tags: java, android, searchview, expandablelistadapter

I am preparing an app for our city to help people find what they want fast and offline. I am using `ExpandableListAdapter` with `SearchView` and I need to make only group items searchable.Is it possible to do that please ? ...

***Here´s my code:***

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.martin.icmt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.martin.icmt.com.martin.icmt.expandablelist.ExpandableListAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    SearchView search;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Nemocnica");
        listDataHeader.add("AKB Martinská Kaliareň");
        listDataHeader.add("TESCO Informačné Centrum");
        listDataHeader.add("Pizzeria Venezia");
        listDataHeader.add("Pizzeria Milano");
        listDataHeader.add("OC Tulip");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> Nemocnica = new ArrayList<String>();
        Nemocnica.add("Otváracie hodiny:                                            nonstop");
        Nemocnica.add("Telefón"+"                   0432 545 684");

        List<String> AKB = new ArrayList<String>();
        AKB.add("Otváracie hodiny:                                    06:00-18:00");
        AKB.add("Telefón"+"                 0524 456 545");

        List<String> TescoIC = new ArrayList<String>();
        TescoIC.add("Otváracie hodiny:                                            nonstop");
        TescoIC.add("Telefón"+"                 043 / 421 81 11");

        List<String> Venezia = new ArrayList<String>();
        Venezia.add("Otváracie hodiny:                                    06:00-18:00");
        Venezia.add("Telefón"+"                 043 / 430 4916");

        List<String> Milano = new ArrayList<String>();
        Milano.add("Otváracie hodiny:                                    08:00-22:00");
        Milano.add("Telefón"+"                 0907 391 404");

        List<String> Tulip = new ArrayList<String>();
        Tulip.add("Otváracie hodiny:                                    09:00-21:00");
        Tulip.add("Telefón" + "               043 / 424 15 00");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Nemocnica); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), AKB);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), TescoIC);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Venezia);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Milano);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), Tulip);
    }
}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
package com.martin.icmt.com.martin.icmt.expandablelist;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.martin.icmt.R;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear to me. Maybe it would help to remove pieces of your code which aren't relevant for the question and try to be more clear about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MrTsjolder firstly thanks for your answer.So I want to achieve that when you write in `SearchView` word pizzeria `ExpandableListAdapter` will show only groups with that word included like Pizzeria Venezia,Pizzeria Milano.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the RolodexArrayAdapter from http://jaysoyer.github.io/Advanced-Adapters/. It's a custom ExpandableListAdapter which supports filtering groups or children...or both at the same time.